# Как связать два контейнера между собой в Docker?

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.8"

#Docker Networks
networks:
  project-network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: ${SUBNET_IP}

#Volumes
volumes:
  mariadb-data-server:
  redis-data:
  clickhouse-db-data:

services:
  &server-service server:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    image: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_server
    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_server_1
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: *server-service
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      REDIS_HOST: redis
      REDIS_PORT: &redis-port 6379
      DB_HOST: mariadb
      DB_PORT: &mariadb-port 3306
      DB_DATABASE: &mariadb-db-name ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_db
      DB_USERNAME: &mariadb-username user
      DB_PASSWORD: &mariadb-password secret
      SCHEDULE_PERIOD: 60
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_host=192.168.221.1 remote_enable=1"
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=Server"
    working_dir: /var/www/server
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"
    volumes:
      - ./server:/var/www/server
      - ./docker/php/server.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    links:
      - 'analytics:analytics'
    depends_on:
      - analytics
      - mariadb
    networks:
      - project-network

  &analytics-service analytics:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    image: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_analytics
    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_analytics_1
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: *analytics-service
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SCHEDULE_PERIOD: 60
    working_dir: /var/www/analytics
    ports:
      - "8091:8091"
    volumes:
      - ./analytics:/var/www/analytics
      - ./docker/php/analytics.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - project-network

  &nginx-service nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_nginx_1
    ports:
      - "8089:80"
    volumes:
      - ./server:/var/www/server
      - ./analytics:/var/www/analytics
      - ./docker/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: ${VIRTUAL_HOST}
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 8089
    working_dir: /var/www
    depends_on:
      - *server-service
      - *analytics-service
    links:
      - 'server:server'
      - 'analytics:analytics'
    networks:
      - project-network
```

default.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name localhost server.local;

    root /var/www/server/public;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass server:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 1000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name analytics.local;

    root /var/www/analytics/public;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass analytics:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 1000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Dockerfile php

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq install -y \
    libonig-dev \
    build-essential \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    git \
    vim \
    zip \
    unzip \
    openssl \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    sqlite3 \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    libsqlite3-dev  \
    curl

# Clear cache
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get update -yqq && \
    apt-get install -y apt-utils && \
    pecl channel-update pecl.php.net

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget git unzip \
    && pecl install xdebug-2.9.0 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql zip mbstring tokenizer bcmath
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin/ --filename=composer

# install redis
RUN pecl install -o -f redis \
    &&  rm -rf /tmp/pear \
    &&  echo "extension=redis.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/redis.ini

RUN pear install PHP_CodeSniffer

RUN /usr/local/bin/phpcs --config-set show_progress 1 && \
    /usr/local/bin/phpcs --config-set colors 1 && \
    /usr/local/bin/phpcs --config-set report_width 140 && \
    /usr/local/bin/phpcs --config-set encoding utf-8 && \
    /usr/local/bin/phpcs --config-set severity 1

RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" docker-user && \
    echo "docker-user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

# Clean
RUN apt-get clean
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /var/cache/*

# Change current user to docker-user
USER docker-user
```

[image: Запущенные контейнеры]

Контейнеры собираются корректно и оба сайта можно открыть в браузере. Но если я пытаюсь курлом обратиться к analytics.local из server.local (curl http://analytics), то получаю ошибку "curl: (7) Failed to connect to analytics port 80: Connection refused". Другие порты из конфига тоже пробовал указать, ошибка аналогичная. Что я упустил при настроке?

Comment: @RomanKonoval, я так же пробовал curl analytics:8089, ошибка была таже "curl: (7) Failed to connect to analytics port 8089: Connection refused". А по 9000 порту я правильно понял, что нужно в ports добавить - "9001:9000" и в конфиге для nginx указать fastcgi_pass analytics:9001 ?

Comment: @RomanKonoval Дополнил описание вопроса

Comment: @RomanKonoval потому что порт 8089 порт слушает nginx, и в браузере по нему все доступно. А вот связи между контейнерами получается нет

Comment: @RomanKonoval, спасибо, настроил так: для контейнера добавил порт, получилось: ports: -"8088:8088" - "8089:8089". А в конфиге для nginx  соответственно для каждого контейнера сделал Listen 8088 и Listen 8089. а курл из контейнера curl nginx:8089 и заработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Но если я пытаюсь курлом обратиться к analytics.local из server.local (curl http://analytics), то получаю ошибку "curl: (7) Failed to connect to analytics port 80: Connection refused".

Это не работает так как вы ожидаете. Когда идет запрос на `analytics:80`, то это запрос именно к контейнеру `analytics`. В нем должен быть процесс который слушает порт и этот порт должен быть выставлен наружу контейнера.

Если используется web сервер (как в вашем случае `ngingx`), то обращение делается (и соответственно доступ клиентам дается) только через web сервер, а приложение открывается только для web сервера, т.е. порты открыты только внутри сети `project-network`, которую создает в данном случае `docker-compose`, чтоб nginx мог сделать запрос на тот порт, на котором приложение слушает. А доступ извне к `analytics` должен быть закрыт и напрямую к `analytics` должен обращаться только `nginx`.

> порт 8089 порт слушает nginx

При обращении к контейнеру nginx все будет работать, а если вы обращаетесь к `analytics` - не будет, что вы и наблюдаете, т.к. `analytics` этот порт (ровно как и 80) не слушает.

Таким образом решение, это обращаться к приложению через `nginx` предварительно отобразив необходимые порты в `analytic` (для доступа из `nginx`) и в `nginx` (для доступа извне) в разделе `ports` конфигурации сервиса в `docker-compose.yaml`.